# Java heap space error while creating ArrayList of large number of objects?

Tags: java, arraylist, heap-memory

I have created an ArrayList (Java) of my custom class objects with a size around 3000.
But when I run my code it gets the error "Heap space error".

I want to keep thousands of objects in an ArrayList at runtime without getting out of heap space.

How can the heap space error be avoided?

Comment: increase your heap by specifying the -Xmx parameter when launching the virtual machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error (64MB heap size)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap-s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you need to pass your program more memory.

Try running it like this:

```
java -Xmx256M MyApp
```

`-Xmx` sets the maximum heap size for Java.  Putting M afterwards means megabytes, and G afterwards means gigabytes. So you can always do this if you have a bunch of memory:

```
java -Xmx1g MyApp
```

Answer (score 2):

Increase the Java heap size with the `-Xmx` Java system property. For example, give it as

```
java -Xmx1024m Main
```